# 3DS Max - Rendering surface normals

Tags: 3dsmax

I tried using google to find an answer to this question but I kept finding results related to applying normal maps to surfaces. What I want is very different.

I have a very simple model (think cube) which I render as an diffuse image (only use ambient lighting). I want to place this rendered image in a 3d scene (a game) and have light bounce off of it. To have dynamic lighting effects, I need to know the normals of every pixel of the diffuse map.

So my question is, how can I render my model to not show texture or color, but to show its normal "color"? I'm not interested in the normal maps! I want the normal map mapped onto the model. Is there a way to do this in 3ds max?

Cheers,

Rene

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, nevermind I managed to get it done using a plugin called "NormalTexMap" (http://www.scriptspot.com/3ds-max/scripts/normaltexmap). It allows you to create a material which you can render as diffuse or 100% self illuminated and it will contain the normals version of your render.

I am creating a tutorial for it to display on my portfolio. once it is done I will post the link here. :)